# Old PSU as 5v/12v power supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I removed all unnessesary cables from some old 200W PSU and added connectors, so I can use it as Power supply.

But there is problem :D When I turn PSU on (this is one without green start wire) I have only 4v/9v on output.
I know old PSU must have some load to work properly, but is there way how to disable this?
I dont want to drain 2A just to stay on.

Comment: You need load on the +5V rail before you have regulated output. Add a resistor, fan, lightbulb or something as load. No real way around it without pretty much rebuilding the entire thing.

Comment: @winny I know but I dont want to drain power as waste. Is therevother way? Some way to disable this

Comment: The other choice is to use a completely different PSU.

Answer (score 2):

Your power supply may be one that requires a minimum load.  OEM supplies intended to be embedded into equipment where the load is somewhat known would often be like this.  Typically the minimum load is 10% of the maximum load, but of course only the datasheet can tell you for sure.

Since you don't seem to know anything about this power supply, try putting a 5 Ω or so power resistor across the 5 V output and see what happens.  If that seems to help but still doesn't quite get you there, try 2 Ω or even 1 Ω resistors.  Be mindful of the power these resistors need to dissipate.  The 5 Ω will dissipate 5 W, the 2 Ω 12.5 W, and the 1 Ω 25 W if the supply output is actually held at 5 V.

In 5 V and 12 V supplies, especially those intended for computer use, the 5 V output was often considered as the "main" one.  It was tightly regulated, as long as the load conditions were met.  The 12 V output then is what it is, but usually not more than 500 mV or so off from nominal.  You probably don't need a minimum load on the 12 V, but you'll just have to experiment unless you can find the datasheet.

Comment: I loaded 5v rail with 5Amps and 12v rail have 13V with 1A current draw :D